# flutter/dart, why a static field is set twice?

Tags: flutter, dart, static, field

my code is:

```
class Constants {
  Constants._();

  static IrisLocaleDelegate localeDelegate = _prepare();

  static IrisLocaleDelegate _prepare() {
    print('prepare.....');                  <<-- this line print twice
    return IrisLocaleDelegate();
  }
 }
 
 class Initial {
    Initial._();

    static Future<bool> init() async {
        /// when this line is call,  [prepare.....] is print for 2th time.  why?
        MyLocalization.setDelegate(Constants.localeDelegate);
        ...
    }
 }

 
 main(){
    runApp(MyApp());
 }
 
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 
 
    // it is simpled
    return MaterialApp(
        ...
        
        builder: (context, home) {
            Initial.init();    <<- call init
            return home;
        }
    );  
 }
```

Why? Shouldn't the static field be created once?

Most interestingly, I used the these without changing  inside previous two apps and I had no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I removed all `import '...';` from header of files and then add one by one again.

I did not understand the reason.